# A function with non-vanishing derivative at a point gives a coordinate chart at the point.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $p\in M$. Suppose we have $f\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $df(p)\neq 0$. Then there exists $U\ni p$ open and $x^i\in C^\infty(U)$, $i\in \{2,\dots,n\}$, such that $(U,(f,x^2,\dots,x^n))$ is a chart at $p$.

---

I think one can the use the rank theorem directly. That is, there exists a chart $(V,x)$ such that  $f|_{V}=x^1$. So $(V,(f,x^2,\dots,x^n))$ (the original chart) does the trick and we are done.
*Is this very short answer correct?*

Alternatively, I though of using another argument (similar to part of the proof of the rank theorem)
Take a chart $(V,x)$ and reorder coordinate so that $\partial_1 f(p)\neq 0$. Define a map $\phi:V\to\mathbb R^n$ by $\phi(p)=(f(p),x^2(p),\dots,x^n(p))$. Then we have
$$D\phi(p) =\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_1 f(p)& \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf 0& \delta^i_j
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus, $D\phi$ is non-singular at $p$ (it is just the identity), hence, by the inverse function theorem, it is local diffeomorphism over some $U\subset V$. Thus, $(U,\phi=(f,x^2,\dots,x^n))$ is a chart.

Is any of these two answers correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is the correct one (though $D\phi(p)$ is not necessarily the identity as you claim). The first approach doesn't even prove anything. Just because at a single point we have $f(p)=x^1(p)$, it doesn't mean you can replace $x^1$ with $f$ (not even in a small neighborhood of $p$). Also, you didn't use the assumption $df(p)\neq 0$ (and clearly by dropping this hypothesis, the claim becomes false, as shown by the counterexample $f=0$).

For example, say our manifold is the trivial $M=\Bbb{R}^2$, and let $(x^1,x^2)$ be the usual Cartesian coordinate chart. Let's say $p=(0,0)$, and $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(a,b)=b$, i.e $f=x^2$. Then, $df=dx^2$ is in fact nowhere vanishing, and at the specific point $p$, we have $f(p)=x^1(p)=0$. Imagine what would happen if we were to replace $x^1$ with $f$; we'd get $(f,x^2)=(x^2,x^2)$, which is obviously not a diffeomorphism, no matter how small of a neighborhood of $p=(0,0)$ you restrict to.

Comment: As a fun exercise, you should try to generalize the statement to when you have $k$ functions $f_1,\dots, f_k$ (i.e figure out the correct hypotheses, and conclusion).

Comment: Thanks for noting that $D\phi(p)$ is not necessarily the identity (though by carrying out the proof in a similar manner to the rank theorem, you can show it is.

Comment: For the my first attempt, I did use $df(p)\neq 0$ as a matter of fact I can not use the rank theorem without it. It makes $f$ of (full) rank 1 and so I can use the rank theorem. Since it is of full rank at $p$, it is full rank at a neighborhood around $p$. The rank theorem makes $f$ the projection on first coordinate (after reordering coordinates) over an open neighborhood, the one to be used.

Comment: I am sorry, but for the counter example, I do not understand why you set $f=x^1$ after defining it to be $x^2$. Without reordering coordinates, leave it as it is. To my understanding, the rank theorem guarantees the existence of neighborhoods such that locally we have a projection. Reordering is what makes it the projection on the first here. So for this case, swap $x^2$ with $x^1$

Comment: @AGHGAS When I said you didn't use the assumption $df(p)\neq 0$, I was referring to your 'short answer'. There, all you used is that $f(p)=x^1(p)$ for some $(V,x)$. Your use of the rank theorem/IFT is correct (besides the identity claim... but it is invertible and that's all that matters) and I wasn't objecting to that.

Comment: @AGHGAS in the counterexample, indeed, I defined $f=x^2$, where $(x^1,x^2)$ is the identity chart. But I am not setting $f=x^1$ afterwards. Rather, I am saying that if I were to follow the (incorrect) argument in your 'short answer', then *'$(f,x^2)=(x^2,x^2)$ does the trick and we are done'*. Clearly, this is an absurd line of reasoning, and that's what I was trying to point out. We can't just arbitrarily remove $x^1$ from the chart and replace it by $f$ with the sole justification being that $f(p)=x^1(p)$.

Comment: Please note that in my short answer, I am using the rank theorem. I wrote above " I think one can the use the rank theorem directly. That is, there exists... "This is what I said in the short answer using the rank theorem implies the existence of $V$ such that a function of full rank is the projection onto the first $k$ coordinates. So the chart I get in the short answer is the one from the rank theorem involving coordinate reordering. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138211/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-aghgas).